# Trying to add huge digits

Tags: java, addition

I'm working on this project and wondering if anyone could help me out. As of now, my program works for two same digit integers, but when it comes to two different digits, my program goes crazy. Look at my code:

This is pretty much the last part of this project and I'll be done. I have not learned [arr1 > arr2 ? blah : blah ] yet. so please  don't suggest something like that. What I want:

```
input: 500
input2: 50
output: 550
```

or

```
input: 50
input2: 500
output: 550
```

Test1:

```
input: 500
input2: 50
output: 100
```

I appreciate all your help.

Comment: "my program goes crazy" - no, it doesn't. it does something that is perfectly logical based on the instructions you've given it. Because it's a *program*. If you want help, you need to tell us what it is doing, exactly. i.e. what are you getting instead of your desired output?

Comment: this seems complicated. Why dont you convert the arrays to ints and then just add them?

Comment: re:"Why don't you convert the arrays to ints". This is a pretty stock homework problem. The inputs can be of an length, so you can't assume that the numbers will fit into an int (or into a long even, which most profs will have a specific testcase for). If it was homework, one just use the BigInteger class, though it would defeat the point.

Comment: @drewmoore when input1 is 500, and input2 is 50, i get 100. & michael I actually am doing that, that's why i have char2Integer.

Comment: Come up with some examples where it doesn't work correctly and show those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original problem was lost in the time I spent writing your code, and making my own `reverse`, `char2Integer`, and `pad` functions. But if I remember it was in your loop where you tried to remove the leading whitespaces. Anyways, here is what I have so far, which seems to work perfectly:

```
public static void  main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input int1: ");
    char[] firstInteger = sc.nextLine().toCharArray();
    System.out.print("Input int2: ");   
    char[] secondInteger = sc.nextLine().toCharArray();

    int[] num1 = char2Integer(firstInteger);
    int[] num2 = char2Integer(secondInteger);

    sum2(reverse(num1), reverse(num2)); //different length, assumed num1 is bigger
}

public static void sum2(int[] num1, int[] num2)
{
    //int over = num1.length-num2.length;
    int[] sum = new int[num1.length+1];
    //The pad function pads the array with 0 so there are no out of range exceptions
    num1 = pad(num1, sum.length);
    num2 = pad(num2, sum.length);

    for (int i = 0;  i < num1.length; i++)
    {
        sum[i] = sum[i] + num1[i] + num2[i];

        //if an element exceeds a value of 10
        if (sum[i] >= 10)
        {
            sum[i] = sum[i]%10;
            sum[i+1]++;
        }
    }
    sum = reverse(sum);
    for (int i = 0; i < sum.length; i++)
        System.out.print(sum[i]);
}
```

And here's the pad function I wrote just for you.

```
public static int[] pad(int[] toPad, int length)
{
    int[] returnArray = new int[length];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < toPad.length; i++)
        returnArray[i] = toPad[i];
    for (int j = i; j < returnArray.length; j++)
        returnArray[j] = 0;
    return returnArray;
}
```

It doesn't remove the leading zeroes, I'll leave that to you. I can't do ALL the work now, can I?

Comment: Just what I wanted. Perfect! You are my savior. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Editted for relevance**
I'll explain what is going wrong, you need to adjust your algorithm quite a bit to get it working properly.

You're over is going to = 1. You check j to over, meaning your loop will run exactly once (in this case). sum is initiated as being 3 digits long, and then you set `sum[0] = 0 + 0`. sum is now [0, 0, 0]. Then in the next for loop, you check if `sum[2] == 0`, and if it is increment sum[0] by 1, not sure why. I think you actually want to 'continue' and keep checking for zeroes until the first digit has actually been printed, then continue printing all digits including zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, but arguably cheap solution, make the number be the same length. (Example code here is assuming non-negative numbers).

First see which is the longer one, and swap so that num1 is always the longer (if they aren't equal length:

```
if(num2.length > num1.length) {
    //this is only true if num2 is longer than num1. We just swap them using a temp
    int[] temp;
    int[] temp = num1;
    num1 = num2;
    num2 = num1;
}
```

Make a new array (num_temp) of length of the max number,then copy shorter one into it, then pad with zeros. (Wrapping this all in a if(num1.length != num2.length) would be a touch cleaner).

```
int[] num_temp = new int[num1.length];
for(int i=0; i < num_temp.length; i++) {
    if(i < num2.length) { 
        // if we are still within the actual number
        num_temp[i] = num2[i];
    } else {
        // we're beyond the actual number at this point, just pad with 0's
        num_temp[i] = 0;    
    }
}
num2 = num_temp; //swap padded number in place.
```

Ok, now you have two numbers, num1 and num2 which are same length (num2 is padded with 0's in the front if needed). Don't know if they completely fixes your code but it basically remove the case where the numbers are different length from being a problem.